# Safari shows mobile version of website

Tags: css, mobile, safari, screen

When viewing the website on firefox and chrome, it looks fine. But viewing it on safari, it shows the mobile version of the site. Why? I havent changed the css for the computer screen when I worked on the responsive design for the mobile.

[www.retorikgruppen.se](http://retorikgruppen.se)

Comment: Think you need to check any extensions you have installed. It looks fine on my safari.

Comment: What kind of extensions? I dont use safari, but the customer I made the website for does and it looks like the mobile version for them. So I need to tell them to check their extensions?

Comment: Well i'd ask them to check if they have any installed. Explain that it works fine on a vanilla install.

Answer (score 0):

October 1 SO suddenly started showing Mobile SO on a stock safari Version 7.1 (9537.85.10.17.1). This has to be coming from SO redirecting to the mobile version of their site.